# scale an SVG group element to have a path centered in viewport dynamically on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js, svg

I want to scale an SVG group element, so that it scales and translates to a point which a path is located on. It means that, when I click on the path, the group has to be scaled and centered to the path in a way that the path fits the height or width of the viewport. I really tried lots of ways, like using `getBBox()` to get height, width, x and y of the path and substract them from the viewports offset. I also tried d3.js to manipulate it. But, I couldn't find a good approach.

This is the HTML including SVG:

```
<div style="width: 700px; height:600px; border:1px solid #d0d0d0; background: #e8e8e8; margin: 0 auto;">
    <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
         viewBox="0 0 255.1 170.1" style="enable-background:new 0 0 255.1 170.1;" xml:space="preserve" width="100%" height="100%">

        <g id="floorplan">
            <path fill="#ED1C24" d="M35.8,51.8h36.3c1.6,0,2.8-1.3,2.8-2.8V22.1c0-1.6-1.3-2.8-2.8-2.8H35.8c-1.6,0-2.8,1.3-2.8,2.8v26.8
                C33,50.5,34.3,51.8,35.8,51.8z"/>
            <path fill="#4A68B1" d="M209.8,114.3h36.3c1.6,0,2.8-1.3,2.8-2.8V84.6c0-1.6-1.3-2.8-2.8-2.8h-36.3c-1.6,0-2.8,1.3-2.8,2.8v26.8
                C207,113,208.3,114.3,209.8,114.3z"/>
            <path fill="#F8991D" d="M134.3,158.8h36.3c1.6,0,2.8-1.3,2.8-2.8v-26.8c0-1.6-1.3-2.8-2.8-2.8h-36.3c-1.6,0-2.8,1.3-2.8,2.8v26.8
                C131.5,157.5,132.8,158.8,134.3,158.8z"/>
            <path fill="#ed2590" d="M13.1,124.3h36.3c1.6,0,2.8-1.3,2.8-2.8V94.6c0-1.6-1.3-2.8-2.8-2.8H13.1c-1.6,0-2.8,1.3-2.8,2.8v26.8
                C10.2,123,11.5,124.3,13.1,124.3z"/>
            <path fill="#356732" d="M161.1,42.5h36.3c1.6,0,2.8-1.3,2.8-2.8V12.8c0-1.6-1.3-2.8-2.8-2.8h-36.3c-1.6,0-2.8,1.3-2.8,2.8v26.8
                C158.2,41.2,159.5,42.5,161.1,42.5z"/>
        </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```

This is what it looks like:[image]

And this is somehow what I want to have after clicking on the red path:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Alexander, beat me to it, but here's a more `d3` implementation:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="d3@4.0.0" data-semver="4.0.0" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div style="width: 700px; height:600px; border:1px solid #d0d0d0; background: #e8e8e8; margin: 0 auto;">
    <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 255.1 170.1" style="enable-background:new 0 0 255.1 170.1;" xml:space="preserve" width="100%" height="100%">
      <g id="floorplan">
        <path fill="#ED1C24" d="M35.8,51.8h36.3c1.6,0,2.8-1.3,2.8-2.8V22.1c0-1.6-1.3-2.8-2.8-2.8H35.8c-1.6,0-2.8,1.3-2.8,2.8v26.8
                C33,50.5,34.3,51.8,35.8,51.8z"></path>
        <path fill="#4A68B1" d="M209.8,114.3h36.3c1.6,0,2.8-1.3,2.8-2.8V84.6c0-1.6-1.3-2.8-2.8-2.8h-36.3c-1.6,0-2.8,1.3-2.8,2.8v26.8
                C207,113,208.3,114.3,209.8,114.3z"></path>
        <path fill="#F8991D" d="M134.3,158.8h36.3c1.6,0,2.8-1.3,2.8-2.8v-26.8c0-1.6-1.3-2.8-2.8-2.8h-36.3c-1.6,0-2.8,1.3-2.8,2.8v26.8
                C131.5,157.5,132.8,158.8,134.3,158.8z"></path>
        <path fill="#ed2590" d="M13.1,124.3h36.3c1.6,0,2.8-1.3,2.8-2.8V94.6c0-1.6-1.3-2.8-2.8-2.8H13.1c-1.6,0-2.8,1.3-2.8,2.8v26.8
                C10.2,123,11.5,124.3,13.1,124.3z"></path>
        <path fill="#356732" d="M161.1,42.5h36.3c1.6,0,2.8-1.3,2.8-2.8V12.8c0-1.6-1.3-2.8-2.8-2.8h-36.3c-1.6,0-2.8,1.3-2.8,2.8v26.8
                C158.2,41.2,159.5,42.5,161.1,42.5z"></path>
      </g>
    </svg>
  </div>

  <script>

    var svg = d3.select("svg"),
        g = svg.select("g");
        
    var v = svg.attr("viewBox").split(" "),
        width = v[2],
        height = v[3];
    
    svg.on("click", function(d){
      g.attr("transform", "translate(" + [0,0] + ")scale(" + 1 + ")");
    });

    d3.selectAll("path")
      .on("click", function() {
        var bbox = this.getBBox(),
            dx = bbox.width - bbox.x,
            dy = bbox.height - bbox.y,
            x = (bbox.x + (bbox.x + bbox.width)) / 2,
            y = (bbox.y + (bbox.y + bbox.height)) / 2,
            scale = Math.min(height / bbox.height, width / bbox.width),
            translate = [width / 2 - scale * x, height / 2 - scale * y];
          
          g.attr("transform", "translate(" + translate + ")scale(" + scale + ")");
          
          d3.event.stopPropagation();
      });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Oh, yes! My solution isn't gracefull, because I didn't use d3, but jQuery only. I will take into account your experience,  @Mark.

Comment: You saved me. Thanks

Comment: @Mark bro love you man i just used your code and solved my own problem related to this thank you so much love you.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`transform` attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#TransformAttribute)  of a clicked `path` element to scale and translate entity. I used a constants for height and width of svg element in the example below, but it helps you to get started.

```js
$("#floorplan path").click(function() {
  if ($(this).attr("transform")) {
    $(this).removeAttr("transform");
    $("#floorplan path:not([transform])").show();
  } else {
    var objRect = this.getBoundingClientRect();
    var svgRect = $("#Layer_1")[0].getBoundingClientRect();
    var scaleX = svgRect.width / 255.1;
    var scaleY = svgRect.height / 170.1;
    var newX = (svgRect.left - objRect.left) / scaleX;
    var newY = (svgRect.top - objRect.top) / scaleY;
    var xScale = svgRect.width / objRect.width;
    var yScale = svgRect.height / objRect.height;
    $(this).attr("transform", "matrix(" + xScale + " 0 0 " + yScale + " " + newX * xScale + " " + newY * yScale + ")");
    $("#floorplan path:not([transform])").hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="width: 700px; height:600px; border:1px solid #d0d0d0; background: #e8e8e8; margin: 0 auto;">
  <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 255.1 170.1" xml:space="preserve">
        <g id="floorplan">
            <path fill="#ED1C24" d="M35.8,51.8h36.3c1.6,0,2.8-1.3,2.8-2.8V22.1c0-1.6-1.3-2.8-2.8-2.8H35.8c-1.6,0-2.8,1.3-2.8,2.8v26.8
                C33,50.5,34.3,51.8,35.8,51.8z"/>
            <path fill="#4A68B1" d="M209.8,114.3h36.3c1.6,0,2.8-1.3,2.8-2.8V84.6c0-1.6-1.3-2.8-2.8-2.8h-36.3c-1.6,0-2.8,1.3-2.8,2.8v26.8
                C207,113,208.3,114.3,209.8,114.3z"/>
            <path fill="#F8991D" d="M134.3,158.8h36.3c1.6,0,2.8-1.3,2.8-2.8v-26.8c0-1.6-1.3-2.8-2.8-2.8h-36.3c-1.6,0-2.8,1.3-2.8,2.8v26.8
                C131.5,157.5,132.8,158.8,134.3,158.8z"/>
            <path fill="#ed2590" d="M13.1,124.3h36.3c1.6,0,2.8-1.3,2.8-2.8V94.6c0-1.6-1.3-2.8-2.8-2.8H13.1c-1.6,0-2.8,1.3-2.8,2.8v26.8
                C10.2,123,11.5,124.3,13.1,124.3z"/>
            <path fill="#356732" d="M161.1,42.5h36.3c1.6,0,2.8-1.3,2.8-2.8V12.8c0-1.6-1.3-2.8-2.8-2.8h-36.3c-1.6,0-2.8,1.3-2.8,2.8v26.8
                C158.2,41.2,159.5,42.5,161.1,42.5z"/>
        </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```

You could correct the [thansformation matrix](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#TransformMatrixDefined) to exact match with expected result will be achieved.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts and help